# If I have ten objects, should there be ten controllers for a Web API?

Tags: api-design, asp.net-mvc-web-api

Is it good design to have a controller for each object of your API?  I know this is a short question, but it's really a fundamental question that I do not know.  Say I have a school or a CRM.  That is a lot of controllers.  I don't know another way to do it, but it feels like a DRY problem.

I am using ASPNET Core if that matters.

EDIT:  By object I meant the actual classes in my project.  But the answers have cleaned that up.  I was thinking about it as a sole one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: "objects of your API" needs some explanation. Are you just exposing database entities through your API? This use of an API bring very little business value compared to actually representing full business operations. http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336912/#341374

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define 'object'

You have one controller for each **resource**. Where a resource is a thing that your API provides (`user`, `customer`, `student`, `sports-team`, etc.)

Resources don't necessarily map one-to-one to **domain objects**. Sometimes a resource is made up of several domain objects and sometimes several resources reference the same domain objects.

A controller may return several **representations** of the same resource, depending on how it's called. Generally it's only two though.

A summary of the resource when returning a list:

```
GET /students

[
    { id: 1, name: "john smith" },
    { id: 2, name: "jane smythe" }
]
```

And a detailed representation when getting a specific item

```
GET /students/1

{
    id: 1,
    name: "john smith",
    age: 27,
    location: "Venezuela"
}
```

If a resource has a strong dependency on a parent resource (e.g. a room cannot exist without the building it's in), I would still have a room controller and handle the dependency via required properties and business logic. (i.e. room must specify `building_id`)

To put the room logic in the building controller is giving it too many responsibilities.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say usually **YES** because if you have less, you will give more than one responsability to the same controller, which is not good.

I see one case where you could not need one controller : It's when an object A has a strong relationship with another parent object B and don't have any independant operation. Then that object A will be managed by the object B of the association. It is possible than in the lower layer (service, database) you will delegate A's operation to a specific class for him, but this will be not visible from the API's view.